# Android two animations with a lot of frames

Tags: android, animation

I'm working on an android application and made 120 frames that mimic a custom countdown. The two animations I need to overlay is the custom countdown and an actual timer. I looked into AnimationSet, but ran into the issue of making an Animation object, where I had to add 120 frames before actually using it, which caused an out of memory exception. The second approach was to use LayerDrawable and show frame by frame. There I ran into the problem of knowing which frames to show and when.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use [Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) it is very
good for animations.For android you add some additional code to animate like [this](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wiki/AndroidUI).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I used SurfaceView. For example: http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/